# Install openVPN 2.4.9 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: openvpn

Is there a way to update openVPN to min. version 2.4.9 in Ubuntu 20.04?

In the Ubuntu repository, there is only version 2.4.7:

```
# apt show openvpn
Package: openvpn
Version: 2.4.7-1ubuntu2
```

I tried to find a debian package to install a newer version but couldn't find any.

Comment: What feature is in the newer version that you need? https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **pin** the version to Ubuntu groovy, it is explained [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) for Ubuntu hardy and intrepid, just replace hardy with focal (20.04) and intrepid with groovy (20.10).